# How do I design for mobile in Dreamwaver while coding in the same css where I have my Desktop code?

Tags: html, css, mobile, layout, dreamweaver

To which part does my layout answer and how can I change it? I have tried changing the screen size in the Dw Design page but I don't think it's responding.

Comment: Either Dreamweaver is not refreshing the page when you're resizing the page-view window or your media query is incorrect or your media query is not even loaded. I would start with the simplest example possible to test it and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

you need Dreavweaver CC to design for mobile, although its not necessary

just use this guide in your css file and add the css for each device

```
    /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    /* Styles */
    } 


/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}


/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}
```